# check if one dataframe values match another dataframe column then set value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe dfScore

```
dfScore = pd.DataFrame([["ringo", 0,0,0]], columns=["Name","Sales total","Problem total","Finance total"])

    Name  Sales total  Problem total  Finance total
0  ringo            0              0              0
```

and a dataframe categories

```
data = [["Finance total", 14], ["Sales total", 4], ["Problem total", 5]] 
categories = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Category', 'ScoreTruth'])

        Category  ScoreTruth
0  Finance total          14
1    Sales total           4
2  Problem total           5
```

What I would like to do is check whether a value from "Category" in categories is contained in the columns of dfScores. If yes then set the value in dfScores column to "ScoreTruth" adjacent value. I've tried using isin to get the indices in dfScores column but that doesn't actually tell me which Category is which index. i.e.

```
index = np.where(dfScore.columns.isin(categories["Category"]))
print(index[0])
>>>[1 2 3]
```

If I try to get the index from isin the other way around I get

```
index2 = np.where(categories["Category"].isin(dfScore.columns))
print(index2[0])
>>>[0 1 2]
```

So now I thought I could do something like this `dfScore.iloc[:,index[0]] = categories.iloc[index2[0]].loc["ScoreTruth"]` to set the values but I get `KeyError: 'ScoreTruth'` Obviously this would only work if I set every row in dfScores using the index[0] anyway which is not ideal.

I would like to output a dataframe that looks like this

```
    Name  Sales total  Problem total  Finance total
0  ringo            4              5             14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `DataFrame.assign`:

```
s = categories.set_index('Category')['ScoreTruth']
dfScore.assign(**s[s.index.intersection(dfScore.columns)])
```

---

```
    Name  Sales total  Problem total  Finance total
0  ringo            4              5             14
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. Intersection was exactly the word I was looking for. Is there a way to take intersection on columns instead of index? Also I got similar results from transposing categories and doing a right merge but then the "Name" value became NaN. Inner merge doesn't work because dfScore has "Name" column. Any ideas?

Comment: @KennethRingo glad i could be of help. can u please elaborate `. Is there a way to take intersection on columns instead of index?`

Comment: you called `s.index.intersection` but I'm wondering how to do it without having to call `set_index()` first, say for instance with merge. The reason I ask is because I might have to add more columns in future.